# How to add a QMenuBar to QWidget in QtDesigner

Tags: qt, qt-designer

Problem:
I have a custom Window Hint within QMainWindow, I need to place QMenuBar under a row of layout
This is how it looks now
[image]
And how it looks like in QtDesigner
[image]

Question:
How to place QMenuBar under custom task bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no way to do this right in QtDesigner
I found a way to replace it by directly changing *.ui file

First step is to open *.ui file in text editor (I'm using PyCharm with *.xml extension)

Second step is look how grid layout works, basically it built like
HTML tag with few options like `row`, `column`, `rowspan`, `colspan`
first two of them are position of the item and other two for positioning
[image]

Following step is to find our QMenuBar widget (my is on 142-154 lines)
[image]
copy and move on

Then we need to create a new item tag in layout tag
[image]
This is the beginning of layout tag, create a  tag after it

Then add coordinates of QMenuBar that you want (mine is row="1" column="0" colspan="5")
[image]
And paste QMenuBar tag into it, then correct indentation
[image]
Now save the file and look at it in QtDesigner
[image]

Using PyUic reveals none problem